# How to log on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with a spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, log4j, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created 2 applications with spring boot. I deployed them on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. One is deployed in a Java environment, the other one in Tomcat.
Tomcat has its catalina.out log, where I can find the logs written by my spring application with log4j. The Java application has a log web-1.log, but it is rolled every hour, and I can only find the last 5 logs.
Is there a better way to log, or to store the old logs (maybe on S3), or to change the retention policy?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [log rotation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html) to S3. You also have the elk stack option but requires effort.
If you want a more aws solution you can utilize cloudwatch. For example you set up your logger with a custom [appender](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html) that sends logs back to cloudwatch.

By using cloudwatch you can have a more friendly way to check your logs.